# crowd groups are not synchronized into sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I use Sonar v6.7 (LTS) with [Crowd Plugin](https://github.com/deepy/sonar-crowd).

I am able to authenticate with Crowd Users who are in a Crowd group "sonar-users" or "sonar-administrators", because these both groups already exist in sonar.

But I want to achieve that sonar synchronizes **all** my Crowd groups. This currently doesn't happen.

---

Currently I have to manually create groups in sonar, e.g. "example-group" and when there is a Crowd user in a Crowd group with the same name ("example-group"), then sonar will automatically add this user to the correpsonding sonar group - but I want to avoid creating these groups manually in sonar.

(How) Is this possible?

Comment: are you using crowd application as a separate attlassian application  or you are using the crowd facility inbuilt in jira ?

Comment: Hi @Tamilan , it's a separate Crowd instance